# Start tmux session and ensure all children terminate

Tags: bash, tmux

I use tmux for development, I have one task running in a window and another one in its own. I've set the convention that the base name of the project directory is the tmux session name.

```
export SESSION_NAME="my-project-name"
tmux kill-session -t "$SESSION_NAME"
tmux new-session -s "$SESSION_NAME" \
                "api.start --monitored" \; \
                split-window "ui.start --monitored" \; \
                select-layout tiled \; \
                set-option -w remain-on-exit on \; \
                set-option -w mouse on \; \
                set-option -g mouse on \; \
                bind-key -n C-c kill-session -t "$SESSION_NAME"
```

All seems to work properly, except if starting a different project with same convention, somehow the CTRL+c in first session thinks SESSION_NAME is the one of the most recent tmux spawned session, which is not what I was hoping.

Answer (score 0):

In the snippet you posted, every appearance of `$SESSION_NAME` is expanded by the shell and each `tmux` gets the expanded value as a command line argument.

<sup>(Even if it didn't and you wanted to expand this `$SESSION_NAME` later inside tmux or inside a shell inside tmux, your `export SESSION_NAME="my-project-name"` may be futile because of [how `tmux` builds the environment](https://superuser.com/a/1424154/432690). The `update-environment` option or `new-session -e …` command may be useful.)</sup>

This includes `$SESSION_NAME` in `bind-key -n C-c kill-session -t "$SESSION_NAME"`. Your `tmux` executes:

```
bind-key -n C-c kill-session -t my-project-name
```

Then for a different project the tmux command is like:

```
bind-key -n C-c kill-session -t different-name
```

The important thing is `bind-key` itself does not target a single session. `bind-key -n C-c …` changes the behavior of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> for the entire tmux server. In your case the last `bind-key` overwrites the previous assignment and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> in any session will `kill-session -t different-name`.

I guess you could use the `key-table` option to set the default key table to something other than `root`, separately for each session. In each new key table you could set a different binding for `C-c`. I haven't tested this, I *think* it may be possible.

If I were you, I would do a simpler thing. I would do this:

```
tmux bind-key -n C-c kill-session
```

`kill-session` without `-t` targets the *current* session, so this binding should do what you want for `my-project-name`, `different-name` or any other session.

Frankly "any other session" is too much for me. I wouldn't want <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to kill everything in my *general purpose* session(s). I would solve this:

- either by leaving `C-c` alone and picking another keystroke as "global SIGINT", then advertently using one or the other;
- or by explicitly "marking" sessions that should use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> as "global SIGINT". It may be something like this:

  ```
  tmux new-session -e 'TMUX_GLOBAL_SIGINT=1' \; \
        bind-key -n C-c if-shell '[ -n "$TMUX_GLOBAL_SIGINT" ]' kill-session 'send-keys C-c'
  ```

  Now in every session that has nonempty `TMUX_GLOBAL_SIGINT` variable in its environment <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> will kill the session. In every session where `TMUX_GLOBAL_SIGINT` is empty or not set <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> will work as usual.

  Notes:

  - For an already started session you can change the setting with `tmux set-environment -u TMUX_GLOBAL_SIGINT` or `tmux set-environment TMUX_GLOBAL_SIGINT 1` (use `-t` to target a specific session, not necessarily the current one).
  - A shell (or another program) started in tmux may inherit `TMUX_GLOBAL_SIGINT`. If it runs `tmux new-session …` then (depending on `update-environment` and such) the new session may also inherit the variable, even without explicit `-e 'TMUX_GLOBAL_SIGINT=1'`. Read `man 1 tmux` and learn about how tmux manages the environment.